# How can I remove or superficial scratches on my wheels?

Tags: wheels, cosmetic, scratch

When getting my tires rotated, the guy scratched a few of my wheels, but when I touch them it’s not rough, it’s smooth. Is there any way to remove these scratches?

I’m getting new wheels and these are going to be my winter beaters but I wanna hold on to them for a while.

The scratches are basically in the same location on every tire, as shown in the picture.

[image: scratched wheels]

Comment: With best regards, I'm sure you could throw some auto wax on there and those slight scuffs would disappear. If you can run a fingernail over them and not feel anything, they're nothing more than slight blemishes. You might even be able to take a microfiber cloth and give it a good rub to remove them.

Comment: Yea I can’t get my nail in them fortunately I’ll try the auto wax/polish thanks paul

Answer (score 0):

Many wheels are clearcoated.  If yours are, you may be able to fill the scratches in with a little clearcoat, then polish them out so that there's an even layer of clearcoat over the scratch.  Since there's no guarantee that the scratch doesn't go all the way through the clearcoat, I wouldn't just polish it out, because then you're just going to end up with a thinner layer of clearcoat, or possibly none.

I wouldn't bother with wax—it will do nothing for you—just polishing compound, with the option of some 2000 grit wetsanding before polishing.